# allow user to postpone scheduled task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I need to allow users to postpone a scheduled task that reboots their machine.

Here is the script I use for the reboot task, I'm not sure how I can give the option to postpone for 30 minutes. I would like for a dialog box to show every 30 mins until they restart.
`

```
    # Create task action
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument 'Restart-Computer -Force'
    # Create a trigger (wednesday at 9:00 AM)
    $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek Wednesday -At 9:00am
    # The user to run the task
    $taskUser = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount - RunLevel Highest
    # The name of the scheduled task.
    $taskName = "Weekly Reboot"
    # Describe the scheduled task.
    $description = "Forcibly reboot the computer at 9:00am on wednesday"
    # set condition to wake computer to run task
    $settingset = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -waketorun
    # Register the scheduled task
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger -Principal   $taskUser -Description $description -Settings $settingset
    $shellObject = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell
    $notification = $shellObject.Popup("Computer will reboot in 30 minutes",0,"Reboot Notification")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is supposed to create a scheduled task... The logic to display a message every 30 minutes must be executed by the scheduled task, not by the script that creates it.

To achieve your goal, you need to modify your script to execute a Powershell code that looks like this (example):

```
while (((New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Popup("Computer will reboot in 30 minutes",0,"Reboot Notification",1)) -gt 1) {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1800
}
Restart-Computer -Force
```

If you want the computer to restart automatically if no user interaction after 30 minutes, simply change the popup parameter as follow:

*...Popup("Computer will reboot in 30 minutes",**1800**,"Reboot Notification",1)*

Also if you execute the task using the SYSTEM account, it won't be able to interact with any logged user's Desktop.
So you need to execute it in the context of the logged user. Modify your script as follow:

```
From this:
    $taskUser = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -LogonType ServiceAccount -RunLevel Highest

To this:
    $taskUser = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupId "BUILTIN\Users" -RunLevel Highest
```

Finally, it is easier to use an encoded command to configure your task for multiple reasons. Simply create a script block and encode it:

```
$RebootCommand = [scriptblock]::Create('while (((New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Popup("Computer will reboot in 30 minutes",0,"Reboot Notification",1)) -gt 1) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1800 } Restart-Computer -Force')
$BytesCommand  = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($RebootCommand)
$EncodeCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($BytesCommand)
```

Then, you use the $EncodeCommand variable to create your scheduled task:

```
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -EncodedCommand $EncodeCommand"
```

Your final script will look like this:

```
# Prepare Encoded Command
    $RebootCommand = [scriptblock]::Create('while (((New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell).Popup("Computer will reboot in 30 minutes",0,"Reboot Notification",1)) -gt 1) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1800 } Restart-Computer -Force')
    $BytesCommand  = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($RebootCommand)
    $EncodeCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($BytesCommand)

# Create task action
    $taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'powershell.exe' -Argument "-WindowStyle Hidden -EncodedCommand $EncodeCommand"
# Create a trigger (wednesday at 9:00 AM)
    $taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -DaysOfWeek Wednesday -At 9:00am
# The user to run the task
    $taskUser = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -GroupId "BUILTIN\Users" -RunLevel Highest
# The name of the scheduled task.
    $taskName = "Weekly Reboot"
# Describe the scheduled task.
    $description = "Forcibly reboot the computer at 9:00am on wednesday"
# set condition to wake computer to run task
    $settingset = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -waketorun
# Register the scheduled task
    Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger -Principal $taskUser -Description $description -Settings $settingset
```

Hope this will help you reach your goal.